# Kerberos installation error, error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualbox, kerberos

I am trying to install python kerbos library, setup.py fails with following. I have already done sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install python-dev(in that order). Here is the complete trackback of the process.

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-UCVN:~/Downloads/requests-kerberos-master$ sudo ./setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to requests_kerberos.egg-info/requires.txt
writing requests_kerberos.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to requests_kerberos.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to requests_kerberos.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'requests_kerberos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'requests_kerberos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos
copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/requests_kerberos/compat.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos
copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/requests_kerberos/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos
copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/requests_kerberos/exceptions.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos
copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos/compat.py to compat.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos/exceptions.py to exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py to kerberos_.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying requests_kerberos.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying requests_kerberos.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying requests_kerberos.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying requests_kerberos.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying requests_kerberos.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/requests_kerberos-0.7.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing requests_kerberos-0.7.0-py2.7.egg
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_kerberos-0.7.0-py2.7.egg
Copying requests_kerberos-0.7.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
requests-kerberos 0.7.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_kerberos-0.7.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for requests-kerberos==0.7.0
Searching for kerberos==1.1.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/kerberos/
Best match: kerberos 1.1.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/k/kerberos/kerberos-1.1.1.tar.gz#md5=09ff604748b8c32dc9698e714f32b8a5
Processing kerberos-1.1.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-CEXP8g/kerberos-1.1.1/setup.cfg
Running kerberos-1.1.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-CEXP8g/kerberos-1.1.1/egg-dist-tmp-snGH08
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: sh:: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: 1:: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: krb5-config:: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on the output here:

```
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: sh:: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: 1:: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: krb5-config:: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: found: No such file or directory
```

it looks like you're missing `krb5-config`. You can install it from the `libkrb5-dev` package in Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: re-factored the answer looks like I was missing a few dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

Just install the package (Ubuntu):

```
apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```

Short and sweet.

Comment: .Thank you! I wanted to add that one may find themselves in this position following an `apt-get autoremove` that was a bit too zealous.

Answer (score 6):

I had to install a few pre-reqs

```
krb5-config
libkrb5-dev
libssl-dev
libsasl2-dev
libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
```

Credit: Sonal and Romain,
please follow the link below, to get all information.
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/hue-user/6pXQWH9OSO4

Comment: Please don't make a link-only answer - copy the relevant snippets into your own answer.

Comment: I didn't need (and `apt-get` couldn't find) the final module `libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit`. Otherwise, these dependencies solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using RHEL8 you need to install `krb5-devel`

```
sudo dnf install krb5-devel
```

which provides `krb5-config`.

Comment: thanks! microdnf install -y krb5-devel work same too