# apt-get installing only docs for krb5-config

Tags: ubuntu, flask, kerberos, apt-get

I am currently setting up my Ubuntu 16.04 VM to use flask-kerberos for authentication. While trying to install it with:

```
pip install flask-kerberos
```

I get a build error:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/base64.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/base64.o /bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
```

The obvious thing was to do:

```
sudo apt install krb5-config
```

However, this does not solve the issue.
When running:

```
sudo find / -iname 'krb5-config'
```

I just get:

```
/usr/share/doc/krb5-config
```

I as well tried to purge and reinstall it, but no luck.

Thanks to everyone for any input already :)

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088355/kerberos-installation-error-error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-i68

Comment: Thank you very much! I did't spot that and google didn't hint me either! Sorry for the duplicate.